# Hello, I just uploaded my themantic child theme and am getting a weird error message every time i try to install a plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just uploaded my themantic child theme and am getting a weird error message every time i try to install a plugin

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/29/7464729/html/wp-content/themes/coolness/functions.php:126) in /home/content/29/7464729/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934

Does anybody know what i should do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code with following guide:-

- Remove blank line before the opening php statement
- Remove blank lines after the closing php statement
- Remove irrelevant echo's in your code

More discussions about this issue in [WordPress Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-output-star-3)

Solutions and reasons [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F)

More and More in stack overflow please use search box in So before posting qustions